# Filter phone numbers in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have phone numbers list in Excel, where in some cells I have two number, in another with plus sign, and I have to filter them like this: 998911234567
[here is excel cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/742vp.png)

Comment: What result do you expect for cells have two numbers.

Comment: I have to delete one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(LEFT(A1,SEARCH(",",A1)-1),A1),"+","")
```

[image]

Comment: It's working, and one more thing, all numbers should start with 998, and the total character should be 12 (like this: 998912345678)

Comment: Then use `="998"&SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(LEFT(A1,SEARCH(",",A1)-1),A1),"+998","")`.

Comment: One more question, how to remove first 998s if the cell contains these numbers

Comment: Substitute function can do it like `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"998","")`.

Comment: If the formula help then please tick mark the answer.